# How to solve nonlinear multivariable systems of equations?

Tags: systems-of-equations, parametric, nonlinear-system

Rather than try to explain it with words I am just going to post an example of what I am trying to do.

Solve: 
$$\begin{align*}
a2^x+b3^y&=42\\
a4^x+b6^y&=156\\
a6^x+b9^y&=342\\
a8^x+b12^y&=600
\end{align*}$$
for $a, b, x, y$ where $a, b, x, y$ can be any real number.

The answer to this example is $x=1, y=2, a=3$, and $b=4.$ (I know this because I made this example up myself).

There are $4$ variables and $4$ equations, so via degrees of freedom there should only be 1 solution set.  But without knowing any of $a, b, x,$ or $y$ in advance or guessing HOW do you solve this problem?

To give a little background I am trying to develop an estimating system using parametrics and I can't assume its a linear system.

Comment: Despite existing an answer for your particular problem, it is worth commenting that, in general, there are no exact solution methods for nonlinear equations. In fact, the rule of thumb "4 variables and 4 equations" does not guarantee the existence of solution, let alone uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the equations to be $$f_i=a\,\alpha_i^x+b\,\beta_i^y-\gamma_i=0 \tag i$$ I should first eliminate $a$ and $b$ using $(1)$ and $(2)$. This then reduces the problem to two variables and we cannot eliminate more.

Now, I should try to minimize $$\Phi(x,y)=f_3^2+f_4^2$$ It is more than probable that, if the $\alpha_i$'s and $\beta_i$'s are in arithmetic progressions, we could arrive to further elimination of $y$ as a function of $x$. In the specific problem you posted, we can get from  $(4)$ $$y=\frac{\log \left(\frac{2 \left(13\ 2^x-50\right)}{7\ 2^x-26}\right)}{\log (2)}$$ and then $(3)$ is the only equation to be solved for $x$.

Comment: How do you eliminate a and b using (1) and (2)? The rest of what you said made sense but its this first part I don't understand.

Comment: $(1)$ and $(2)$ are two linear equations in $a,b$. For sure; $a$ and $b$ are then explicit functions of $x$ and $y$ but we do not care about it. To me, the main goal is to reduce, as far as I can, the dimension of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

a and b can be eliminated in following way:

Step 1: Choose any two equations and solve them for a and b. So, you will have a=f1(x,y) and b=f2(x,y)

Step 2: Consider remaining two equations and again solve them for a and b. So, you will again have a=f3(x,y) and b=f4(x,y) in similar manner as step-1 above.

Step 3 : From above step-1 and step-2, we equate f1(x,y)=f3(x,y) and f2(x,y)=f4(x,y)

Step 4 : Now we have 2 equations and two variables x and y which can be solved easily further.